# phpexcel - comments misplaced in xlsx 2010 workbook

Tags: alignment, phpexcel

When I modify a comment in an excel workbook (2010, 2013) created by PHPEXCEL, the **comment is presented at the very top of the sheet**. The same appears with the phpexcel example's script 05featuredemo.inc. 
I'd like the comment to stay closed to the related cell. To do this, before modifying the comment, I must first change the alignment of the cell. Doing this it works. Another solution is to copy the sheet to a new workbook.

Comment: You present a problem and a work around. What is your question?

Comment: The question is : How to do for a comment  to be displayed just near his cell whent i "modify" it ? I've got a solution but i'm not sure it's the best one.

Comment: My solution is a workaround solution and i'd like to have The good solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code ...**writer/Excel2007/Comments.php** the following line (line 253) is desactivated :

### **//$objWriter**->writeElement('x:Anchor', $column . ', 15, ' . ($row - 2) . ', 10, ' . ($column + 4) . ', 15, ' . ($row + 5) . ', 18');

The solution to my problem is to reactivate this line of code.
Now the comments are staying closed to their cells when i modify them and no more displayed at the top of the sheet.
But there is a new problem : the sizing of the comment that i do in my phpexcel program doesn't work. The solution is to modify the Comments.php source code like this :
$objWriter->writeElement('x:Anchor', $column . ', 15, ' . ($row - 2) . ', 10, ' . ($column + **$pComment->getWidth()**) . ', 15, ' . ($row + **$pComment->getHeight()**) . ', 18');

The Width and Height are respectively a number of cols and a number of rows. So in my program, The Width and Height are no more like "100pt" but a number of cols and a number of rows :
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment($col)->setWidth('**15**');                   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment($col)->setHeight('**20**');

Doing this it works. I just have to modify my code to determine the size of the comments in number of cols and rows.
Question : could this problem be resolved in next version of phpexcel ?